# Unable to load my custom membership provider?

Tags: asp.net-membership, web-config

I was trying to implement a custom membership provider, everything goes well, I can connect, I can change user details, but as soon as I create user, I got this error when it tries to get the user after I complete create a user.

The error is coming from my web.config, it is saying it's a ConfigurationErrorsException, and it also says that the problem is on my type under the config file, I am sure that the provider type I provided is correct, such as

```
type="MyNamespace.MyCustomMembershipProvider"
```

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to post more details.

Comment: Can you post the offending code as well as the error it generates?

Answer (score 7):

When you put the type in, you need to specify the assembly it comes from.

So `MyNamespace.MyCustomMembershipProvider` in `MyNamespace.dll`, would require this configuration:

```
type="MyNamespace.MyCustomMembershipProvider, MyNamespace"
```

Also, in case it's complaining about the default provider, either name your default provider as `SqlAspNetMembershipProvider` (in the XML, not the classname) or set the default provider name on the "`membership`" element in your web.config.

This is how mine looks:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SqlMembershipProvider" 
             type="Barnwell.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, Barnwell.Web.Security" 
        ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the implementation, most likely you have a problem in your CreateUser method of your custom membership provider. Follow the link for more information;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.createuser.aspx